# Dumb question about rational root theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra

In Fraliegh's abstract algebra, he proves the rational root theorem for monic polynomials using Gauss's lemma. However, in his statement (and every other one of this theorem I've seen), the requirement is that the constant term $a_0$ is nonzero, and I'm just wondering why.

Statement: if $f(x)=x^n+...+a_1x+a_0$ is in $\mathbb{Z[x]}$ with $a_0$ nonzero and if $f(x)$ has a zero in $\mathbb{Q}$, then it has a zero $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $m$ divides $a_0$.

Clearly, if $a_0=0$, then $0$ is a rational root and is also a root in $\mathbb{Z}$. Is this the only reason though? Because if $a_0=0$ the statement is obvious?

Comment: It could be - some people have problems with the fact that $0$ divides $0$, and then the "has a zero $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $m$ divides $a_0$" becomes awkward. Or it could be that the case $a_0 = 0$ is indeed obvious.

Comment: If $a_0=0$ then $0$ is a root of your original polynomial and factoring reduces you to the rational root theorem (eventually, unless it's something like $x^n$). This is a case of a theorem only addressing an interesting case instead of the most general case.

Comment: Where is this stated in Fraleigh's book?

Comment: @Bill Dubuque page 215, corollary 23.12

Comment: While the Rational Root Test (and its proof) remain valid if the leading or constant term $= 0,\,$ these cases do not yield useful constraints on the root, since every integer divides $0$. So the hypothesis that these extreme coefficients are nonzero is due to *utility* (not logical neccessity).